# AngularJS: How to access variable from inside a promise and use within the controller?

Tags: angularjs, variables, scope, angularjs-scope, local-storage

I'm trying to declare an array inside a function of a controller that happens after the factory pulls for data, and then access it after the function is done being completed. Here's what I have for my code:

```
app.controller('SignUpController', function ($scope, $http, $location, DailyCounterService, $localStorage) {

    DailyCounterService.GetDailyCountersList().then(function (d) {
        $scope.DailyCounters = d.data;
        $scope.allCounters = [];

        var daySixteen = d.data.filter(function (d) {
            // This is where I'm building the array I want to access later
            $scope.allCounters.push(d.MICounter);

            return d.MIDay === "16";
        });

        console.log($scope.allCounters);
        // This prints in console '[2, 6, 1, 1, 7, 8, 2......]'
        // So the array is now initialized

    }, function (error) {
        alert('Error!');
    });

    // Here is where I want to access $scope.allCounters once again
    // But Can't because doing this:
    console.log($scope.allCounters);
    // prints 'undefined'
    // How would I make $scope.allCounters be able to be accessed here?
})
.factory('DailyCounterService', function ($http) {
    var fac = {};
    fac.GetDailyCountersList = function () {
        return $http.get('/Data/GetDailyCountersList')
    }
    return fac;
})
```

As I've asked in the comments towards the end of my controller, how would I be able to access the variable set in the function prior outside of that function?

Comment: If you want to use $scope.allCounters in your controller initialization you will need to use it in the .then() method as that is the only time it will be available during initialization.

Comment: @jbrown is there anyway at all, with my current setup, where I can make that data accessible outside the `.then()` function? Any sort of local-storage work-around?

Comment: Am I correct in assuming that you want to use $scope.allCounters in controller initialization?

Comment: @jbrown yes, you are correct, but also, afterwards, based on click functions. So, everything is initialized on page load, but also accessed during event clicks later on the same page.

Comment: Ok.  Then no because anything you do outside of the promise resolution (.then()) will execute before the promise is resolved.  Here's a good post on how promises work http://www.webdeveasy.com/javascript-promises-and-angularjs-q-service/

Comment: @jbrown let me ask you one more question then, is there anyway to do what I'm trying to do, keep same functionality of pulling data, by possibly even eliminating the use of promise resolution?

Comment: The promise allows you to make the $http call, which is asynchronous, and handle the results of the call in a callback function.  Without it the call to the api would go unhandled on the client side.  There are other ways to initialize a controller, specifically through the use of a route provider and the resolve property

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, if this controller is associated with a route, then you  can tie up this get code in the resolve attribute of the route provider like this,

```
.when("/signup", {
    templateUrl: "signup.html",
    controller: "SignUpController",
    resolve: {
        allCounters: 
        function(DailyCounterService){
            DailyCounterService.GetDailyCountersList().then(function (d) {
             // Do your stuff
             return allCounters;
        }, function (error) {
             alert('Error!');
         });
        }
    } 
}),
```

and access allCounters in you controller like this,

```
 app.controller('SignUpController', function ($scope, $http, $location, allCounters, DailyCounterService, $localStorage)
```

By this way all counters will always be initialized when your controller is loaded.

More on resolve: http://odetocode.com/blogs/scott/archive/2014/05/20/using-resolve-in-angularjs-routes.aspx